# Passing cell title to another view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

today i have this problem:

Im doing so the title of the First cell of a tableview is show in my "Home" view controller.

This is what i have dun at the moment, but the label in homeviewcontroller is not getting the title text of the first cell.

Reminders.h:

```
NSMutableString *primerevento;

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableString *primerevento;
```

Reminders.m:

```
@synthesize primerevento;

    - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    ....

    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if(indexPath.row == 1){
        cell.textLabel.text = primerevento;
    }
```

HomeViewController.h

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *promediototal;
```

HomeViewController.m

```
@synthesize promediototal

    - (void)viewDidLoad
    {

    [super viewDidLoad];


    ....

    Reminders *viewsiguiente = [[Reminders alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
    promediototal.text = viewsiguiente.primerevento;
    [self presentViewController:viewsiguiente animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

my label on homeviewcontroller appears in blanc, i dont know what im doing wrong, im really trying.

Thanks for your time guys

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do. Is HomeViewController the first controller? viewsiuiente won't have any value for primerevento until it's loaded and you give it a value, so I don't know how you expect to get its value right after you instantiate it.

Comment: 1)homeviewcontroller is my first view controller2)yes, look my code, thats what i know, but i dont know why isnt working, its suposed taht primerevento get the value of the tittle of the first cell

Comment: I'm still confused. Are you trying to SET the title of that first cell from a value you have in HomeViewController, or are you trying to GET a value from the table view? Your title says you're passing the value from the cell title to the other controller, but if HomeViewController is the first controller, you can't pass something to it from the second controller which you haven't even loaded yet.

Comment: im tryng to GET the title cell vaue.  then put that value in my firstviewcontroller. its any way to fix that?. my tableview is with ekeventkit, i want to do this so i can show in my firstcontroller the title on th next-coming event

Comment: But when do you set that title (how and where do you set the value of premerevento)? In the code you show, you are instantiating a new instance of Reminders -- at the time you do that, primerevento won't have any value (as far as I can tell). You need to make it clear what the sequence of events is.

Comment: The title of the events is the title of the event user creates. Im using ekeventkit

Comment: That still doesn't explain how or when you create that event. Show the code for how (and where in the controller's code) you create this event, and be clear about what controller that code is in.

Answer (score 0):

In the homeViewController don't forget to import the .h of the remindersViewController.

```
#import "reminders.h"
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *promediototal;
```

Then in the homeViewController.m where you want your text - promediototal.text = reminders.primerevento.text;

```
@synthesize promediototal

- (void)viewDidLoad
{

[super viewDidLoad];


....

Reminders *viewsiguiente = [[Reminders alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
promediototal.text = reminders.primerevento.text;
[self presentViewController:viewsiguiente animated:YES completion:NULL];
```

Comment: i dont know why it dont let me to put primerevento.text its say text proberty cant be with a nsmutablestring

Comment: Sorry for the late answer, try making the "Primervento" NSMutableString a global variable by adding it in the Application Delegate. Then everytime you want to access it's data you can just call on the AppDelegate and reference the NSMutableString "Primervento".

Comment: I personally would have a "reminders" object and make it have an instance variable called "titleString". Then store the "reminders" object into a NSMutableArray. So whenever you need to access the title you just call on the object stored and retrieve the "titleString" for both the tableCell and the homeViewController.

Answer (score 0):

We have probably still too view code to understand what you are up to. 
There is one thing though:

```
Reminders *viewsiguiente = [[Reminders alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];// 1)
promediototal.text = viewsiguiente.primerevento; // 2)
[self presentViewController:viewsiguiente animated:YES completion:NULL]; // 3)
```

1) What is the purpose of that? Firstyou create a brand new view controller object. As you do not create it from nib (which is fine) it cannot have any poperties set. so `viewsiguiente.primerevento` is `nil` at that point of time.

2) Now you take this nil value and assign it to `promeditional.text` which becomes `nil` to? What is the sense in that? Did you mean?

```
viewsiguiente.primerevento = promediototal.text;
```

3) And now you present the newly created view controller `viewsiguiente`. You did not make any changes to it. That may be fine if you implementation of `Reminders` takes care of the views. But you did not set any value from external.